# Electrical Problem

Tags: light-fixture, light

[image]I have two lights I am trying to install in my garage. The switch for these lights has a black and a white wire. However, when I look at the junction boxes for both of these lights I have a red wire that is live. I do not know what I should do in terms of setting up these lights.

I keep the blacks together and the whites, and ground my lights green wire. But what do I do with the red wire? Am I on the right track or am I missing something?

Cheers

[2]:[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkdBb.jpg[image]
  [3]: [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Posting a picture of the wiring at the light box and the switch box(es) will help get you an answer. We can't see what you see without pictures. I suspect that you have a three way circuit. Are the lights controlled by more than one switch? Like, for example, one by the garage door to the outside and another by the garage door to the house?

Comment: They are controlled off of one switch. I suspect maybe the red wires are coming from another junction bow somewhere.

Comment: Do these pics show us the original wiring in those boxes,  or have you made some changes already?

Comment: I did the dumb thing and not take any pictures before taking the previous lights off. Live and learn.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color coding in North American wiring is pretty terrible, because you have to "make do" with the standard colors in cable.  Fortunately, by sheer luck, your setup is *almost* color coded.  Get some colored electrical tape and we can finish the job.

See in the top picture, where there are 2 black wires and an oddball white. That is standard procedure for wiring a pre-2011 switch loop.  Both here and at the switch, mark the white wire with black electrical tape.  This is actually a Code requirement.

Black is a preferred color code for "always hot".

Noting that cable's partner black wire, mark that with red electrical tape on both ends.  That is not mandatory, but it is about to make all this super simple.

Red is a preferred color code for "switched hot".

On your lights, they probably have a black and white wire.   Mark the black wires with red electrical tape, since presumably you want the lights to be switched.

At this point, everything in all boxes should be color coded properly (just treat a wire taped color X as a color X wire). *Now* you join whites to whites, blacks to blacks and reds to reds.